# Laravel new db with migrations programmatically

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel Backpack for my admin part of the application. Right now after I create a "company" through my backend I call a function on the Company model to do these steps:

1. Create a new database with a name I pass it
2. Check the DB is made
3. Run all migrations from my Company folder

in my CrudController

```
$company->createDatabase( $request->input('db_name') );
```

in my Model

```
public function createDatabase($dbName)
        {
            //Create a new DB with the company db_name attribute

            $new_db = DB::statement("CREATE DATABASE {$dbName}" );

            //Now migrate over all Company specific migrations

            if($new_db)
            {
                \App::make( 'setDbConnection', $dbName );

                return Artisan::call( 'migrate', [
                    '--database' => $dbName,
                    '--path' => 'app/database/migrations/company',
                ]);
            }

        }
```

Right now I will create the new DB just fine but get errors running migrations.

If I have the `\App::make( 'setDbConnection', $dbName );` in there I get:`Application::make() must be of the type array, string given`

If I take that out and just try a migration I get: `Database [MyNewDBName] not configured.`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone doing something similar (mine if for a multidatabase mutlitenant SAAS application) this function works. The IoC command I had before it looked like was taken from Laravel 4. So now I can just use the `Config` command to set my connection and pass that to artisan.

```
        public function createDatabase($dbName)
        {
            //Create a new DB with the company db_name attribute

            $new_db = DB::statement("CREATE DATABASE {$dbName}" );

            //Now migrate over all Company specific migrations

            if($new_db)
            {
                \Config::set('database.connections.company.database', $dbName);

                return Artisan::call( 'migrate', [
                    '--database' => 'company',
                    '--path' => 'database/migrations/company',
                ]);
            }

        }
```