# Create database via API based on Laravel migration file

Tags: laravel, heroku, cloud, devops

I have a school management system built using Laravel and uses MySQL for database. In this system I want to be able to create a separate database for each school, how can I do that programmatically or via API

Answer (score 0):

You are probably heading into an architecture called Multi-Tenant Architecture (MTA), and based on my experience, you can do that using one of these options:

1. External Library, I used [Tenancy](https://tenancy.dev/) before for creating an MTA app, it is pretty awesome.
2. Manually, which has a lot of stuff to cover, but it is the easiest way to understand. For this option, basically you just add the foreign key to all of the object that you want to separate. For example, your database has `schools` and `students` tables, then `schools` is your tenant in MTA, which is the one that you want to make a different database, then `students` is the item that you want to keep separately in each of the database, then you need to add `school_id` to the `students` table.
3. Your wanted answer, which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611659/laravel-new-db-with-migrations-programmatically). I personally do not recommend this because this is just does not make sense that you called an Artisan command when your application is running programmatically.

If you have the time to research into MTA, go for the first option. If you have some time, second option is great, and if you don't have time at all, you can take the third option.